# turn check off radio / labels if input is triggered

Tags: jquery

I am working on a dynamic classification system that allows a user to classify it's products according a specific standard. This whole setup works fine, but reading through the technical specs of the classification, it is possible, if a feature is blank, you can assign a reason why the value has been left blank, (RNV). I decided to do this with labels and radio buttons. This all works fine.

My issue is now that if a user decided to start filling in the value anyway, I want the radio button and it's label to deselect.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" name="EF001391" class="form-control input-sm feature">
      <div class="input-group-addon no-style" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-orange active">
               <input type="radio" class="RNV" name="EF001391" value="NA" checked>
               Not applicable
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-orange">
              <input type="radio" class="RNV" name="EF001391" value="UN">
              Unknown
         </label>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the JQuery

```
$('body').on('change', '.feature', function(e) {        
    $(this).parent().closest("input[type=radio]").prop("checked",false);        
    $(this).parent().closest(".active").removeClass(".active"); 
});
```

However, I cant get it to work, i tried children, closest, sibblings, etc, but I cant seem to target and remove the class and turn of the value, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest traverses upward and you're already starting at the parent of "feature", which is your input-group div. It won't find it.
Starting with the feature element, I use next() to get it's next sibling (the DIV right under your number input). From there I use find to get the inputs because children() will only search 1 level down and that would not find the other inputs because they're within the label tags.

```
 $('body').on('change', '.feature', function(e) {

    $(this).next().find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);
  
  $(this).next().find("input[type=radio]").parent().removeClass('active');
 
  
});
```

Comment: ahh, thanks for clearing that up, didnt realize that closest went up in the dom, rather than down.

Comment: Just FYI, you can also take parent().removeClass() from the second line of code and just append it to the end of prop(), this way it's not duplicating the next() query. (or optionally store the result into a variable)  I kept it all separate to make it easier to see what's going on in the answer.